# If you can chain classes within a selector, how come nth-child and other functions dont work?

Tags: html, css

So i was thinking:  You can chain things in CSS such as:

```
#test.winning.button
```

but can it do something more complex like this:

```
div:nth-child(even):nth-last-child(1);
```

I mean, i know this can be done in jQuery by doing simply:

```
$("div:nth-child(even)").last()
```

but didnt know if this is plausible with vanilla css.

Here is a JSFiddle for dabbling that i was trying to test against.
https://jsfiddle.net/au5f7djd/

Comment: Pseudo selectors should be chainable quite normally.

Comment: Check this: http://nthmaster.com/ Might be useful

Answer (score 2):

The example you link to doesn't work because:

```
div:nth-child(even):first-child{
```

The 1st child will *always* be odd. 1 is an odd number.

```
div:nth-child(even):nth-last-child(1){
```

… will work if the 1st last child is even. This requires that you have an even number of children. The example you link to has 9 children, so the 1st last is currently an odd numbered one. Add or remove a `div` and it works.

When you combine selectors you are looking for elements that match *all* the conditions. Counts still take all the elements into consideration, they don't just count within the previously matched group.

Comment: i was thinking that it would get the first child from the even subset.  because similarly, i wanted to get the last child from an odd subset.